# Connecting timeout for WebSockets

Tags: websocket

I can't find any information which specify the timeout for building the connection with a WebSocket server. This means, how long can the state "CONNECTING" be active before it changes to "CLOSED"? When the target host doesn't exist the state changes almost immediately, this is easy to find out. But what happens if the DNS lookup takes longer or the server is busy?

The same question arises for the "CLOSING" state when the connection goes through the closing handshake procedure. If the connection fails here, how long does it take until onClose() is called?

Are these two timeouts browser specific? If so, does anyone know any concrete numbers?

Comment: The timeouts could be a browser-specific thing.

Comment: It's browser-specific. The the WebSocket specs are silent on this.

Comment: Thank you guys. Is anybody aware of concrete numbers?

Comment: They are browser specific as they happen 90% in a browser. As well your application should not ever depend on such unstable "issues".